# How to catch up OAuthForbiddenException : You are not a sandbox user of this client InstagramKit IOS, SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am using instagramKit to login with a Instagram user. If I try to logIn with a user that is a sandbox user of the app, I have no problem. However, if I login with a user that isn't a sandbox user, The app show me a web view with the follow message :

> OAuthForbiddenException : You are not a sandbox user of this client

And I cannot go back, so I have to close the app and open again.  I want to find a way to dismiss this view in this case.

The code :

```
func connectWithInstagram() {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height))
    self.webView!.delegate = self
    self.webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: InstagramHelper.sharedInstance.connectWithInstagram()))
    self.view.addSubview(webView!)
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    guard let url = request.URL else {
        return false;
    }

    if request.URL?.scheme == "http" || request.URL?.scheme == "https"{
        self.setInstagramButton()
        return true
    }

    do{
        guard let _ = try InstagramEngine.sharedEngine().receivedValidAccessTokenFromURL(url) as? AnyObject else {
            // success!
            self.webView?.removeFromSuperview()

            let urlArray = url.absoluteString.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
            let accessToken = urlArray.last
            let accessTokenArray = accessToken?.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
            let instagramId = accessTokenArray?.first
            UserDataManager.saveInstagramId(instagramId)
            return true
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

How can I dismiss this view when the it shows me the OAuthForbiddenException  Exception In order to avoid close the app and open again?